# Document on click runs weird

Tags: javascript

```
"use strict";

$(document).on("click", ".EXLRequestTab > a ", function() { 
        alert("I am an alert box!");

var abc = document.createElement("a");
var linkText = document.createTextNode("InterLibrary Loan Request");
abc.appendChild(linkText);
abc.title = "";
abc.href = "https://illiad.some.edu/";


        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("selected EXLRequestSelectedServiceTitle");

        x[0].parentElement.parentElement.appendChild(abc);
});
```

This code runs very well when alert("I am an alert box!") command line added. However, when I comment out this alert("I am an alert box!"), when I click the tab EXLRequestTab, it did not append child abc.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you add the HTML that accompanies this JavaScript to your question please?

Comment: Are you using jQuery?